# Current user in field

Tags: column, people-picker, user, elements-xml

Can I set the default user in a user field to the current user -> [Me]? How is it done?
The xml I already have is:

```
<Field ID="{F117832D-E722-460C-A083-162C55B701F9}" Type="User" Name="PrimAdministrator" 
       DisplayName="Primary Adminstrator" Required="TRUE" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" 
       ShowField="Name" ></Field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343574/how-can-i-set-a-user-field-to-a-default-value-of-a-user-currently-logged-in-thro

Another option could be to set it in a workflow

Answer (score 2):

Attaching event receiver could be one of the solution.

If you need that the default values are set when the new item form opens, then you need javascript/jQuery on the New Item form.

Also, even if there is no browser option for it, you can set the default value using C# code, here is what you can do for a User/Group field:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("site url"))
{
   SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
   SPList list = web.Lists["My List with the field"];
   SPField fld = list.Fields["My User Or Group Field"];

   SPUser usr = web.EnsureUser("DOMAIN\\login");
   SPFieldUserValue defValue = new SPFieldUserValue();
   defValue.LookupId = usr.ID;

   fld.DefaultValue = defValue.ToString();
   fld.Update();

   list.Update();
}
```

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f2de4f24-21dc-452b-96c4-1da9633bfb38/default-value-for-person-or-group-column-in-a-sharepoint-2010-custom-list

http://kenkumar.blogspot.in/2011/06/sharepoint-2010-set-default-value-for.html

http://spjsblog.com/2010/05/28/get-or-set-value-for-sharepoint-field-in-newform-editform-and-dispform-get-only-in-dispform/

Answer (score 0):

Pushpendra's code only work in SharePoint 2010.

View this add-on([SharePoint Default Value Add-On](http://www.sharepointadd-ons.com/sharepoint_default_value)), which make it possible.

Set "Current User" (User who is adding item) as default value.

[image]

Comment: link is dead (and iirc cost something wild like £100 anyway)